# Why is there no implicit conversion from std::string_view to std::string?

Tags: c++17, string-view

There is an implicit conversion from `std::string` to `std::string_view` and it's not considered unsafe, even though this surely may cause a lot of dangling references if the programmer *is not careful*.

On the other hand, there's no implicit conversion from `std::string_view` to `std::string` using same argument but in the completely opposite fashion: *because the programmer may not be careful*.

It's lovely that C++ has a replacement for a raw `const char*` pointer, while making it super confusing and stripped to the bone:

- Implicit `const char*` -> `std::string`: **OK**
- Implicit `std::string_view` -> `std::string`: **NOPE**
- Assignment `std::string` = `const char*` : **OK**
- Assignment `std::string` = `std::string_view`: **OK**
- Appending `std::string` += `const char*` : **OK**
- Appending `std::string` += `std::string_view`: **OK**
- Concatenation `const char*` + `std::string`: **OK**
- Concatenation `std::string_view` + `std::string`: **NOPE**
- Concatenation `std::string` + `const char*`: **OK**
- Concatenation `std::string` + `std::string_view`: **NOPE**

Am I missing something or is this a total nonsense?

In the end, how useful is this string view without all the crucial pieces that make it similar to `const char*`? What's the point of integrating it into the ecosystem of *stdlib* while not making the last step to make it complete? After all, if we need an object that represents a piece of a string we could write our own. Actually, a lot of libraries already have done that, years ago. The whole point of making something standard is to make it useful for widest range of use cases, isn't it?

Are they going to fix this in **C++23**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a question, this is a rant.

Comment: This probably belongs on https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp (some C++ committee members read that.)

Comment: It seems some unfair that this question, whose discussion would help many programmers, has been closed

Comment: @Barry, this is indeed a question.  It's also a rant, but that doesn't make it not a question.  The OP is expressing legitimate shock, quite understandable IMO, which doesn't at all detract from the technical legitimacy and usefulness of the question.  It would be great if the question could be reopened.

Comment: _"Seriously, whats't up."_ Sounds like a question to me. ;)

Comment: Copy-initialzation `std::string` = `std::string_view` : **NOPE**

Comment: Funnily enough I came here because I tried to copy a string_view to a string and to do it I need to construct a new temporary string: `response+="<tag>"+std::string{sv_payload}+"</tag>";

Comment: @graham.reeds At least the committee is satisfied that this is **pretty verbose**.

Answer (score 61):

The problem is that `std::string_view` -> `std::string` makes a **copy** of the underlying memory, complete with heap allocation, whereas the implicit `std::string` -> `std::string_view` does not. If you've bothered to use a `std::string_view` in the first place then you obviously care about copies, so you don't want one to happen implicitly.

Consider this example:

```
void foo1(const std::string& x)
{
    foo2(x);
}
void foo2(std::string_view x)
{
    foo3(x);
}
void foo3(const std::string& x)
{
    // Use x...
}
```

The function `foo2` could've used a `const std::string&` parameter, but used a `std::string_view` so that it is more efficient if you pass in a string that isn't a `std::string`; no surprises there. But it's less efficient than if you'd just given it a `const std::string&` parameter!

- When `foo2` is called with a `std::string` argument (e.g. by `foo1`): When `foo2` calls `foo3`, it creates a copy of the string. If it had a `const std::string&` argument, it could've used the object it already had.
- When `foo2` is called with a `const char*` argument: A `std::string` copy has to be made sooner or later; with a `const std::string&` parameter it gets made earlier, but overall there's exactly one copy either way.

Now imagine `foo2` calls multiple functions like `foo3`, or calls `foo3` in a loop; it's making exactly the same `std::string` object over and over. You'd want the compiler to notify you about this.

Comment: From my experience, most often `std::string_view` is used to optimize parsing of a string. The result of parsing, obviously, cannot be stored in a view, so it should be transferred to a permanent storage (`std::string`). Why should it be so verbose? After all, I am in control and i **should** know where view *may* be converted.

Comment: What you describe is a bad design. A bad design of other piece of code **should not** be a reason to make design of `std::string_view` also bad. Also, programmer, seeing `foo1()` and `foo3()` **should** know about conversions. And if we ignore all this, how does explicit helps in your example? Because of bad design, programmer still forced to create `std::string`, doesn't he?

Comment: @GreenScape I don't understand the point in your first comment; maybe you could add some example code to your question? I also don't really understand your second point; what exactly is bad design? The fact that `foo3` takes a `const std::string&`? That was extremely common before `std::string_view` existed, and there is a lot of that code lying around. Or the implementation of `foo2`? Because I agree (although it's bad implementation not bad design) but it can easily happen by accident, and you would want the compiler to catch it.

Comment: Just to address the last part of your second comment (sorry I missed it initially): If you get the compiler error in a function that would need a `std::string` multiple times, you could decide to construct it once at the beginning of the function and reuse it for the multiple function calls. Or you could change the function signature to take a `const std::string&`.

Comment: @ArthurTacca what would you say if `string_view` was replaced by `const char*` in your example ? it's been decades we deal with const char* -> string implicit conversion. `string_view` helps to manipulate temp `const char*` memory, it is obvious that at a moment the `string_view` will trigger allocation by converting into a string, and it is the responsability of the user to ensure where. More, an old code built with `const std::string&` everywhere couldn't translate easily with string_view because of that missing implicit conversion.

Comment: @Juicebox That is a totally different scenario. For a start, string literals are `const char*` so there needs to be an implicit conversion so that `f("foo")` works when `f` takes a `std::string` (there would be riots in the street if it didn't). Second, you only use `string_view` if you are specifically trying to avoid memory allocation - that's the whole point of my answer - but that is certainly not the whole point of `const char*`.

Comment: @Juicebox "it is obvious that at a moment the string_view will trigger allocation by converting into a string" Yes it is obvious that a conversion to `string` will trigger an allocation, but there is an implicit conversion then it is not obvious when that conversion is happening. It is very much the responsibility of the compiler, not the user, to catch mistakes that it can. And is it really a problem to write `f(string(x))` rather than `f(x)` if you want to do a conversion?

Comment: This would be much less annoying if they provide some easy way to do the conversion explicitly.

Comment: @NO_NAME As my last comment said, if `f` takes a `std::string` and `x` is a `std::string_view` then you can just write `f(std::string(x))`. I can't imagine anything explicit that could be simpler than that. What were you thinking of?

Comment: @ArthurTacca Sorry, I didn't realize that the generic constructor works for `std::string_view`.

Comment: You say passing `std::string_view` is less efficient than using `const std::string &`.  [This test dramatically shows the opposite.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5262072/Cplusplus-17-New-Features-and-Trick#std::string_view)  What conditions would make your statement true?

Comment: @psimpson Lots wrong in your comment (a) I said `string_view` is *more* efficient; (b) the answer to "what conditions...?" is in the same sentence from my answer: when  "you pass in a string that isn't a `std::string`" (because it avoids a copy); (c) in that microbenchmark you actually do have a `std::string` so there should be no difference; the benchmark is clearly bogus because outputing text to a console, even just copying to a buffer to output later, is hugely more expensive than the different between those parameter types when you start with a `std::string`.

Comment: It was probably a misstatement, but your post says, after the code block "But it's less efficient than if you'd just given it a const std::string& parameter!".  Perhaps that line should be removed, or edited if the "it's" was intended to refer to, maybe, `std::string`.  And, yeah, I don't do that sort of benchmarking, generally, so your answer made me suspect they might have chosen a poor test.  In reality, you are both trying to say the same thing.  I appreciate your response.

Comment: @psimpson Ah sorry, yes I do also say `string_view` is less efficient than `const std::string&`, but only in the particular situation where the `string_view` is in the middle of the `const std::string&` sandwich shown in the code snippet. That is clear if you read that sentence in context with the sentence or two beforehand. What's more, that situation can't happen in practice without an explicit cast (or compiler error!) because there is no implicit cast – remember, that's what the original question was about, and that example is meant to show why the lack of implicit cast is a good thing.

Comment: I DID read it out of context, probably because I was asking a different question.  The inefficiency lies in foo2::foo3, not in foo1::foo2, which is really what I need to think about as I apply it right now.  Thank you!

Comment: Out of these five assignments, three work and two don't. Very hard to understand for the beginner, why this is the case (`v` is always a `std::string_view`): `std::string s1(v);` (ok), `std::string s2{v};` (ok), `std::string s3 = v;` (fails), `std::string s4; s4 = v;` (ok), `struct A { std::string a; }; A a { v };` (fails). The first and third case look the same, so why does one work and the other not? Case number 3 and 4 also look similiar, but only one works. And the same is true for case 2 and 5. I understand the rant of the thread opener very well.

Comment: @KaiPetzke I definitely agree those examples are problematic. They're especially troublesome because they relate to initialisation, which is infamously a mess in C++.  I never claimed that every aspect of `string_view`'s interface is perfect, only that the problem I described is bad enough that fixing it by making the constructor explicit outweighs the convenience of leaving it implicit. Making every aspect of `string_view` clean is simply not possible in C++. Maybe an analogous class could be implemented cleanly in Rust, especially thanks to its lifetime management.

Comment: It was mentioned above that "string literals are `const char *`". Well, they are not, that's the point. They are `const char[N]&`, where N is a size_t value. That's how `std::string_view` accepting a `"foo"` is cheaper than `const char *`: the view captures the length of the literal at compile time, whereas all the `const char *` accepting APIs have to figure out the length of the string each and every time.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica This question is about implicit conversions *from* `string_view`, whereas it seems like you're talking about conversions *to* `string_view`. That's a whole different topic.

Comment: @psimpson that "test" is absolutely worthless as it a SINGLE instance of a micro-benchmark that does not take any other factors into consideration. Just switching the 2 testcases around dramatically changes the result (in my case 1 tick for `string_view`and 0 for `const string&` ). Not only that - it is mostly measuring io-stream there.

Answer (score 22):

### Because expensive implicit conversions are undesirable...

You only listed *one* implicit conversion out of your entire set of examples: `const char*` -> `std::string`; and you're asking for another one. In all of the other 'OK'-marked functions - allocations of memory are *obvious/explicit*:

- Assignments: When you assign anything to an owning object with variable storage size, it is understood that an allocation may be necessary. (Unless it's a move-assignment, but never mind that.)
- Append I: when you append to an owning object with variable storage size, it is even more obvious it will need to allocate to accommodate the additional data. (It might have enough reserved space, but nobody guarantees this about strings.)
- Concatenations: In all three cases, memory is allocated for the result *only*, not for any intermediate object. Allocation for the result is obviously necessary, since the operands of the concatenation remain intact (and can't be assumed to hold the result anyway).

Implicit conversions in general have benefits and detriments.  C++ is actually mostly stingy with these, and inherits most implicit conversions from C. But - `const char*` to `std::string` is an exception. As @ArthurTacca notes, it *allocates memory*. Now, the
C++ core guidelines [say](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ro-conversion):

> **C.164: Avoid implicit conversion operators**
>
> **Reason**:
> Implicit conversions can be essential (e.g., double to int)
> but often cause surprises (e.g., String to C-style string).

and this is doubly the case when the unintended conversion performs expensive operations like allocation, which have side effects, and may make system calls.

---

PS - `std::string_view` has quite a few gotchas; see this CppCon 2018 talk by Victor Ciura:

[Enough `string_view` to hang ourselves with](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwP4YCP_0q0)

So remember it's not some kind of universal panacea; it's another class that you need to use with care, not carelessness.

### ... an explicit constructor is sufficient.

There [actually does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520057/1593077) an explicit constructor of `std::string` from `std::string_view`. Use it - by passing `std::string{my_string_view}` to a function taking a string.

Comment: Why? Is it such a disaster? What is the worst-case scenario? An extra allocation? It can be easily profiled and optimized, if necessary. On the other hand, we have a handicapped API. Handicapped API is not that easy to work-around. Such an API is disgusting to use: tons of boilerplate just to avoid this 'mysterious catastrophic implicit conversion'. And remember, we're talking about a non-ordinary type. That has much more severe gotcha: dangling references. And we're fine with that. But not with an implicit allocation, oh no!

Comment: @GreenScape: We're talking about what happens _by default_, not about what's allowed to happen at all. Also - why sneak in an extra allocation which the programmer didn't ask for? However...  this makes me think of something...

Comment: @GreenScape: Why don't you just  use the explicit constructor?

Comment: As I wrote in my original comment: it's a boilerplate. I know nothing about your experience, but according to mine, if you want to use string_view effectively, you're going to use it *everywhere*. Which means that you're going to use explicit `std::string{foo}` *everywhere*. Which is a unnecessary boilerplate and isn't worth trading it just "to avoid accidental implicit conversions". It just isn't worth it!

Comment: "Which means that you're going to use explicit std::string{foo} everywhere" - if this is the case, then you probably shouldn't be  using string_view in the first place. Just use strings then. Most of the point of using string_view's in the first place is to avoid these allocations.

Comment: That is the point. Desing your API as lightweight as possible (`string_view`) and then let clients decide how to use it. Alas, making decision in favour of `string_view` forces the clients to use boilerplate.

Example: you have a const HTTP request object. To avoid allocations you can index it using `string_view` and let clients extract data as: `std::optional<std::string_view> find_header(...)`. This allows you to store the whole blob in a single buffer. It's allocation friendly, move-friendly, but not client friendly.

Comment: @GreenScape, I totally agree with you. I decided to replace "std::string const &" with "string_view" for all possible function arguments in my libs, and that ended up costing me literally days of work boilerplating my code to fix all the sudden implicit conversion errors (which were all desirable conversion in the context of my program). It got me thinking that the comittee is so wrong on this matter, because is not their role to patronize the way I code.

Comment: There are many problems with this inconsistent design decision. I brought it up with members of the standard committee before C++17 was finalized, but their desire to prevent silent allocations trumped all. I told them adding an annoying inconsistency into the standard in an attempt to prematurely optimize user code would not even work, as people would work around it, that the inconsistency could result in other sub-optimal code, and that static analysis would be a _much_ better solution. Alas, my concerns were dismissed and so here we are.

Comment: @JosephThomson: Well, I've been bitter for a while about the rejection of uniform call syntax proposals for what I would call "parochial" reasons, so... I guess I can sympathize.

Comment: There are lots of super convenient dynamic typed languages out there. The prime reason to use a language like C++ is because you want to control every aspect regarding performance. Thus requiring the user to actually spell out such an allocating conversion seems to be the right design decision

Answer (score 5):

One of the reasons string views are useful in embedded environment is precisely because they don't do dynamic allocation and we get safety due to the length being passed as part of the view. So for me the lack of an implicit cast to std::string is not a deal breaker because that would require dynamic allocation. A silent conversion would be an error in this environment and have to be found and removed.

Comment: Excuse me, but how much C++ code is embedded code? To be truthful, your domain ditches half of C++ features anyway (forbids their use). So, given how much code you have to write anyway, to replace ditched features of stdlib, you can easily write your own string_view.

My vision is: stdlib must target the most common and widespread use-cases. And make the use of it features as comfortable as possible. All other corner cases can be written for specific domain. Ie, that's why stdlib doesn't have BTree or Trie implementation.

Comment: @GreenScape not saying I like working with embedded C++. But a lot of embedded code is written in c++, mbed-os, pigweed, arduino, etl. string_view was a welcome addition for developing in embedded c++. I don't think the standard was written with embedded development in mind, but string_view just so happens to work well for embedded development.

Comment: The is a surprisingly large amount of embedded  C++ code out in wild because it actually often compiles into more efficient code then C. Also there are many features of C++ that are really useful such as templates, constexpr, function overloading, much better type safety, RAII etc.std::string_view increases safety for no additional effort on the developers part, so its really useful in embedded.