# c++ std::map<std::string, int> use at with std::string_view

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a `std::map<std::string, int>`. Is there any way to use its `at` method with `std::string_view`? Here is a code snippet :

```
std::string_view key{ "a" };
std::map<std::string, int> tmp;
tmp["a"] = 0;
auto result = tmp.at(key);
```

Here is the output I have from clang 12.0

> error: no matching member function for call to 'at'
>
> auto result = tmp.at(key);

Comment: Hm, I get 'no matching member function to call at' using clang...

Comment: @Dmitry did you enable c++17 ?

Comment: Yes, even c++17 with cmake

Comment: @TonyTannous `std::string_view` was introduced in C++17

Comment: Here is a demo. https://godbolt.org/z/Tn5jh1 `.at` is expecting `std::string`. That is why you are getting error. Just wrapped key with std::string.

Comment: @TonyTannous `.at` is actually expecting `const std::string&`, which means temporaries are allowed to be created and passed to it.  And a temp `std::string` can be created from a `std::string_view`, as your demo (and mine) proves.  So, there has to be something else going on to prevent the compiler from being able to create that temp implicitly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but that leads to a string construction, right? So I'm not able to use at with pure string_view

Comment: @Dmitry `std::string(key)` constructs a `std::string`, yes.  No, there is no way you can use a `std::string_view` by itself when the `std::map::key_type` is `std::string`, a conversion from `std::string_view` to `std::string` is required since that is what the `std::map` is expecting.

Comment: @Dmitry seems to be a known issue: [Why is there no implicit conversion from std::string_view to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525238/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau ok, thanks for the link - now it's clear for me what I am missing

Comment: @Dmitry yeah, I just forgot that the conversion from `std::string_view` to `std::string` was not supported *implicitly*, only *explicitly*.

Answer (score 8):

Three things are required for something like this to happen:

1. The map's comparator must be a transparent comparator (requires C++14, but you're already using `string_view` which is C++17, so this is a moot point).
2. The `at()` method must have an overload that participates in overload resolution when the container has a transparent comparator.
3. the parameter must be convertible to the map's `key_type`.

Neither of these are true in your example. The default `std::less` comparator is not a transparent comparator, there is no such overload for `at()`, and `std::string` does not have an implicit conversion from `std::string_view`.

There's nothing you can do about `at()`, however you can do something about the comparator [namely using the (transparent `std::void` comparator)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void), and then use `find()` instead of `at()`, which does have a suitable overload:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>


int main()
{
    std::string_view key{ "a" };
    std::map<std::string, int, std::less<void>> tmp;
    tmp["a"] = 0;

    auto iter=tmp.find(key);
}
```

[More complete demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c6r1av)

Answer (score 3):

There is no *implicit* conversion from `std::string_view` to `std::string`, that is why you get a "no matching member function" error. See: [Why is there no implicit conversion from std::string_view to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525238/)

There is a `std::string` constructor that will accept a `std::string_view` as input, however it is marked as `explicit`, so you will have to do this instead:

```cpp
auto result = tmp.at(std::string(key));
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/2pfRm-ZOO)

Same if you wanted to use the map's `operator[]` with `std::string_view`:

```cpp
tmp[std::string(key)] = ...;
auto result = tmp[std::string(key)];
```

Comment: Having to instantiate a string just for a lookup is so painful I'll always try to [avoid](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r3fjdEWTz) that with all my forces