# Default value for Template C++ string

Tags: c++, templates

I was writing a program for hashtables. The hashtable has pairs. `first` is a string and `second` belongs to a template class.

Need to initialize the template class as a string to return a default value when looking up strings.

```
template<typename T>
struct default_value;
template<>
struct default_value<int> {
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};

template<>
struct default_value<double> {
    static constexpr double value = NULL;
};

template<>
struct default_value<float> {
    static constexpr float value = NULL;
};

template<>
struct default_value<string> {
    static constexpr string_view value{""};
};
```

Currently, I am getting an error when I do the above for the `string`. I understand I cannot use `constexpr` for string and so I decided to use `string_view`. I have imported `string_view` already

Comment: Try `char *` type.

Comment: `static constexpr double value = NULL;`: no, no, no, no... The macro `NULL` should not be used in C++; use `nullptr` instead; this way the compiler would have yielded an error for the this nonsensical line: You're initializing a number with a constant reserved for pointers; If you indeed need to pull this stunt, you should use `reinterpret_cast` to indicate this is done on purpose, but in this scenario you shouldn't. You could btw provide a reasonable default with `template<class T> struct default_value { static constexpr T value {}; };`, i.e. use the default initializer(covers numbers).

Comment: Is the assumption correct that `string_value` in the last 2 sentences of the question should be `string_view`? Since C++20 the default string constructor is `constexpr` btw.

Comment: Why do you need a default value? `std::unordered_map` works without one.

Comment: I think what you're seeing is that you can't implicitly assign a `string_view` to a `string`, e.g. `string x = string_view { "..." };`. This question asks why: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47525238/1863938