# Why doesn't std::string have a constructor that directly takes std::string_view?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, constructor-overloading, string-view

To allow `std::string` construction from `std::string_view`there is a template constructor

```cpp
template<class T>
explicit basic_string(const T& t, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

which is enabled only if `const T&` is convertible to `std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>` ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)).

In the meantime there is a special deduction guide to deduce `basic_string` from `basic_string_view` ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/deduction_guides)). A comment to the guide says:

> Guides (2-3) are needed because the std::basic_string constructors for std::basic_string_views are made templates to avoid causing ambiguities in existing code, and those templates do not support class template argument deduction.

So I'm curious, what is that ambiguity that requires to have that deduction guide and template constructor instead of simply a constructor that takes `std::basic_string_view`, e.g. something like

```cpp
explicit basic_string(basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> sv, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Note that I'm not asking why the constructor is marked explicit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no implicit conversion from std::string\_view to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525238/why-is-there-no-implicit-conversion-from-stdstring-view-to-stdstring)

Comment: @ph This is another question, whereas this question is "Why is there no explicit not templated std::string constructor from std::string_view?"

Comment: @phuclv S.M. is correct, I'm not questioning explicitness of the constructor

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The ambiguity is that `std::string` and `std::string_view` are both constructible from `const char *`. That makes things like

```
std::string{}.assign("ABCDE", 0, 1)
```

ambiguous if the first parameter can be either a string or a string_view.

There are several defect reports trying to sort this out, starting here.

https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2758

The first thing was to make members taking string_view into templates, which lowers their priority in overload resolution. Apparently, that was a bit too effective, so other adjustments were added later.

Comment: Is this the only ambiguity? Can you possibly elaborate what other adjustments were added later?

Comment: @oliora  I read "other adjustements" to mean the deduction guides.