# Error when returning a string from a function that has a string_view as parameter

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, string-view

I am working on the following code:

```
std::string myFunc(std::string_view stringView)
{
    size_t i = stringView.find_last_of("/\\");
    if (i != std::string::npos)
      return stringView.substr(i + 1);
    return stringView;
}

int main()
{
    std::string testString{"TestString"};
    std::string_view testView{testString};
    std::string test{testView};

    return 0;
}
```

where I am passing a `string_view` to the function `myFunc()`. The function returns a `std::string` since I've read that it's better to not return a `string_view`.

However, the compiler is giving the following two errors:

```
<source>: In function 'std::string myFunc(std::string_view)':
<source>:19:31: error: could not convert 'stringView.std::basic_string_view<char>::substr((i + 1), ((std::basic_string_view<char>::size_type)std::basic_string_view<char>::npos))' from 'std::basic_string_view<char>' to 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'}
   19 |       return stringView.substr(i + 1);
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
      |                               |
      |                               std::basic_string_view<char>
<source>:20:12: error: could not convert 'stringView' from 'std::string_view' {aka 'std::basic_string_view<char>'} to 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'}
   20 |     return stringView;
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
      |            |
      |            std::string_view {aka std::basic_string_view<char>}
```

What is the correct way to solve this if I want a `std::string` as returned type? See the link for the compiler error snapshot
Thanks in advance

Creating a local string and initialize it with the `string_view` could be a solution (?)

[compilation_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wexe.png)

Comment: Yes, creating a local string is exactly what you need to do, since evidently `std::string` doesn't have a constructor that takes a `std::string_view`.  That seems like an oversight, but not much you can do about it.

Comment: *"since I've read that it's better to not return a `string_view`"* `std::string_view` has no ownership, so you have to be careful about lifetime when returning `std::string_view`, it seems correct for your code to return `std::string_view`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion from `std::string_view` to `std::string`.
You can see more about it here:

[Why is there no implicit conversion from std::string_view to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525238/)

However, since C++17, there is an **`explicit`** [`std::string constructor`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (look at overload (10)) that accepts a `std::string_view`.  You can use it to construct a `std::string` to return from your function:

```
std::string myFunc(std::string_view stringView)
{
    size_t i = stringView.find_last_of("/\\");
    if (i != std::string::npos)
        return std::string{ stringView.substr(i + 1) };
    return std::string{ stringView };
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you answered this.  I did some research and discovered the comment I left on the question wasn't quite correct.